# Application Portability(On iPhone And iPad)

Tags: iphone, ios

how can any application be implemented to run effectively on iPhone And iPad as well.. can't there be any consequences regarding Image resolution screen size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iPhone and iPad are two very different devices. You probably want different UI-layouts depending on which device you're running the app on. Apart from that, the difference isn't very big. You can use most of your code on both devices.

Comment: Yes, you need to make a GUI design for iPad and one for iPhone. It's not something that just happens magically.

Comment: @rptwsthi There are people that specializes on designing UIs. For instance where I work I always get mockups of the UIs I implement. If you don't like designing UIs you should consider hiring someone to do it for you. I'm pretty sure no one will give you an answer explaining automatic UI-design, so you might as well accept this one.